# Quick cast with indicator shows only range and not hitbox/area of effect

Tags: league-of-legends

Same question was asked already, but the answer didn't work for me. On a new account my quick cast indicator shows the range of ability (circle), but doesnt show hitbox (line in which the spell will go). On my main account all the settings seem to be exactly the same as new account, but on my main indicators do show the hitbox/area of effect. What do I need to do to make indicator on new acc show the hitbox/area of effect/line?

Comment: Could you add a link to the near-duplicate question so we know what answer has been provided and hasn't worked for you?